# how to set Content-Transfer-Encoding as 8-bit in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

i am sending mail from my asp.net application using c#.

a part of my code

```
  Message.SubjectEncoding = Message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

this sends the **charset**=utf-8 but **Content-Transfer-Encoding**:base64

i have gone through [Problem sending email with SmtpClient in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456815/problem-sending-email-with-smtpclient-in-c-sharp) but i have not found how to set Content-Transfer-Encoding as 8-bit

Comment: As far as I know, SMTP is a 7-bit protocol that only supports pure ascii. Base64 is a workaround for that since it converts 8-bit data to 7-bit. What is the actual _problem_?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it is an interesting one.

I have found a solution here:
https://idevelopdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/content-transfer-encoding-systemnetmailmailmessage/

Basically, you have to use AlternateViews, as then you can set the Content-Transfer-Encoding. To 7bit only though, not 8bit, but that was good enough for me.

I am not sure why MS made such a mess, but took me hours and hours of finding the right recipe for sending both HTML and plain text the way they should be sent.